# Python messing with a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have defined a small function that is supposed to compute some summary stats for a time series

```
def health(data):
    # remove all nan entries
    import pandas

    nav_daily = data.dropna()
    d = pandas.Series(index=['Valid', 'First', 'Last', 'Months'])

    d['Valid'] = nav_daily.size
    d['First'] = nav_daily.index[0]
    d['Last'] = nav_daily.index[-1]
    d['Months'] = nav_daily.resample(rule="M", how="last").size

    return d
```

This works if First and Last are commented out. I don't think there is a problem with pandas here. I get the error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
...
        d['First'] = nav_daily.index[0]
      File "H:\thomas\envPython\L01\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 640, in __setitem__
        self._set_with(key, value)
      File "H:\thomas\envPython\L01\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 680, in _set_with
        self._set_labels(key, value)
      File "H:\thomas\envPython\L01\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 691, in _set_labels
        % str(key[mask]))
    ValueError: ['F' 'i' 'r' 's' 't'] not contained in the index
```

I am using Windows 8. Is this some problem with Ascii or " vs ', etc.?

Comment: Have you tried `d.ix["First"]`?

Comment: Ok, the ix trick is doing it, but there must be a deeper reason for this problem. I thought I can treat a pandas Series very much like an ordered dict - or am I completely wrong here...

Comment: This is not a trick. I don't know what exactly is happening here (which version of pandas is this?), but the `[]` operator is highly overloaded. By using `.ix` you are forcing the use of the index. What is the value of `nav_daily.index[0]`? Is it by chance an iterable?

Comment: It's because you're indexing on a Series and not a DataFrame perhaps

Comment: nav_daily.index[0] is a date. I am using Pandas 0.13.1